# onClick in a for loop is not firing

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, onclick

What I have below is code from a recent [tutorial of Computer Arts magazine](http://www.workofjonas.com/experiments/CAtut2/). What I have tried to do is implement an `onClick` function within the loop so that each `div` is clickable and will load the corresponding webpage.

I have an array, currently with only one set of values but you can get the idea of multiple values that are similar:

```
var itemsHTML = '',
        items = [
        {
          itemType:'ani',
          itemName:'Show Reel 10-11',
          path:'thumb_showreel.jpg',
          urlPath:'showreel.html'
        }];
```

And the loop that takes the info from the array (Please take note of the `onClick` - this is my input, everything else is from the tutorial:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var type = items[i]['itemType'];
      var name = items[i]['itemName'];
      var path = items[i]['path'];
      var urlPath = items[i]['urlPath'];
      itemsHTML += "    <div class=\"element " + type + "\"  style=\"background-image:url('portfolio/" + type + "/" + path + "')\" onClick=\"document.location='http://www.thepapertorium.co.uk/'" + urlPath + "\">";
      itemsHTML += "      <div class=\"label\">";
      itemsHTML += "        <h1>" + name + "<\/h1>";
      itemsHTML += "      <\/div>";
      itemsHTML += "    <\/div>";
    }
```

This same `onClick` was taken from my header's banner. It works correctly there, so I figured I could paste it into here, and, naturally, adhere it to the syntax that the `for` loop requires, but I have had no luck. Please help with this simple dilemma!

Comment: Could you provide an example of the HTML after it has been built? Let the script run, view the source and edit the question to add what the script produces.

Comment: Using JS to concatenate strings of JS embedded in HTML? This is a nightmare to debug (as you have discovered). Use standard DOM manipulation instead of messing with innerHTML.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem may be in single `'` - it should go to the end of URL:

`onClick=\"document.location='http://www.thepapertorium.co.uk/" + urlPath + "'\"`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is `document.location` instead of `window.location`. But I wouldn't use javascript for that, you could use an anchor tag instead:

```
itemsHTML += "    <a class=\"element " + type + "\"  style=\"display: block; background-image:url('portfolio/" + type + "/" + path + "')\" href=\"http://www.thepapertorium.co.uk/" + urlPath + "\">";
```

Comment: document.location is not the problem, but you are correct in not needing javascript to change the location

Comment: thanks @mplungjan, I didn't know `document.location` existed, always used `windows.location`...

Comment: Feel free to vote mine up too. I want some love here as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Quotes issue - I simplified them for you by reversing the " and '

I also added ; cursor:pointer and changed document.location to window.location since that is more correct. Actually bfavaretto is indeed correct in saying you do not need a javascript to change the page - a link will even give you the pointer for free

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QmxX4/)

```
itemsHTML += '<div class="element ' + type + '" style="background-image:url(\'portfolio/' + type + '/' + path + '\')" onClick="window.location=\'http://www.thepapertorium.co.uk/' + urlPath + '\'">';
```

Next time try jsfiddle.net and firebug